# Most efficient method to check whether user has new mail?

Tags: php, mysql, database, messaging

I have a simple and generic internal messaging service on one of my PHP/MySQL sites, with a unique `messageID`, `from`, `to`, `subject`, `message`, `time`, and `isRead`.

In general, what is the best way to check that a user has new mail?

Should I store a simple binary trigger on the main Users table that gets switched to 1 when anyone sends them a message, and then have the user check for that 1 on every pageload, and if there is one, alert them to the new mail (and set it to 0 whenever they go to their Inbox)?  But what if it was spam and we deleted it before the user read it?

Or should I store the `messageid` of the last message the user read, and then do a check for the latest message and see if it's more recent than the last one that he read, and if so alert him?  But then how and where should I store this info?

Is there another, more efficient method considering we would have to check for new messages on every pageload?

If the user goes to his Inbox, it should no longer show him that he has "New Mail" for any of the messages that were in his Inbox at the time he checked it, regardless of whether he's actually clicked to read them or not.

Thanks!

EDIT:  Some of my users access my site from very basic phones that don't have cookies or even Javascript, so please keep that in mind.

Comment: Would your message object not have a status field for states such as "New" or "Read" you can query? When looking at hotmail/gmail or the likes you can switch a read mail back to unread, I'm assuming they are using some sort of status field for that too.

Comment: @Francois:  I do have an `isRead` field as I mentioend in my OP, but that is if that particular message was actually read or not.  The "New Message" alert is a bit different because it should alert the user when the have new messages since the last time they checked their Inbox.  Does that make sense?

Comment: how about using a websocket? from the server you could send a message to the browser in an async way, then the browser could do whatever needed with that info

Comment: @marcelog:  Can you explain a bit more, I'm unfamiliar with websocket.  Also, please keep in mind that some very basic mobile phones use this site, so anything "too" advanced (like AJAX) won't work with them and I don't want to exclude them.

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be push notification from server, like stackoverflow does, using html sockets.

[jquery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-graceful-websocket/)

But keep in mind that is not supported by all browser, so will need to fall back to ajax polling.

About spam i would suggest only notify user after spam checking if done, if possible.

Your solution to store next to user with set bit sounds right, (also you could store number of new message, instead of bit)

Comment: Unfortunately some of my users use very basic mobile phones that don't even work with AJAX, so this doesn't seem like it's an option for me as I do not want to exclude any current users.  Also, the set bit solution I mentioned would be a problem if I deleted SPAM, because a user would still have the "New Mail" alert, would then go to their Inbox, but would not see any new messages (since the SPAM was deleted).  That's why I can't finish wrapping my head around the best way to do this...

Comment: well if you delete and mark as spam then update user table also.

Comment: But how will I know whether it was just the SPAM that was "New" or if there were other messages that were also new (in which case I would *still* want to show the user the "New Mail" message?

Comment: Who checks if message is spam?

Comment: It's a manual process, and then all that user's messages are deleted (including the ones they sent).

Comment: Well i don't know if you could do anything about it until you know how  to distinct spam automatically. You could update users table when you are deleting spam, or show only manually confirmed messages :)

Answer (score 0):

In your users table, store the count of new messages, and update when needed.

AJAX polling can be expensive in serverside (the `select count(*) from ...`  can be expensive when your DB became large, and you need to  do it, for example, one check per minute).

If the user just browsing in your website, and have no new messages, you can just skip `select` more information about messages.

Comment: How would I update that count, based on what event?  Would I update it on every User's pageload?  Whenever someone sends them a message?  When?

Comment: When other user send a message (1 time). User can read the field 1 time per minute or more...